# Simplify product of complex numbers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I am trying to take product of a complex number with its conjugate. When I take

```
A*Conjugate[A] // FullSimplify
```

The output is as desired

```
Abs[A]^2
```

But when I try

```
FullSimplify@(A*Conjugate[A]*B*Conjugate[B])
```

The output is

```
A B Conjugate[A] Conjugate[B]
```

Why mathematica is not showing the output as

```
Abs[A]^2 Abs[B]^2
```

I am using Mathematica 11.2.0.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` does the work: `A*Conjugate[A]*B*Conjugate[B] // ComplexExpand`.

Comment: @rmw - You have let `ComplexExpand` assume that `A` and `B` are real-valued. The OP is working with complex variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
simplify = 
  Simplify[ComplexExpand[#, Variables[Level[#, {-1}]], 
     TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]] &;

A*Conjugate[A] // simplify

(* Abs[A]^2 *)

simplify[A*Conjugate[A]*B*Conjugate[B]]

(* Abs[A]^2 Abs[B]^2 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. This will save a lot of time in my calculations :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat counterintuitive, but Mathematica might indeed think that `A B Conjugate[A] Conjugate[B]` is simpler.

```
LeafCount[Abs[A]^2 Abs[B]^2]
LeafCount[A B Conjugate[A] Conjugate[B]]
```

> 9
>
> 7

Notice that `LeafCount` is not the precise `ComplexityFunction` used by `FullSimplify`, but it may still give you an idea.

In the end, simplification is always a matter of taste.